# Ruby Calulate Sum from Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, sum

I'm using rails to try and calculate the total of a specific column in my database. I'm using this at the moment:

```
@total = Product.sum (:cost)
```

Which works and returns the combined cost of everything in the table. What about if I'm trying to do that from data which is already in an array? For example:

```
@products = Product.where('date >= ? AND date <= ?', Date.today.beginning_of_month.to_datetime, Date.today.end_of_month.end_of_day.to_datetime)
```

Can you then do the same thing on that array of products?

Hope someone can help! Ta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply append `.sum` to the resulting ActiveRecord object:

```
Product.where('date >= ? AND date <= ?',
 Date.today.beginning_of_month.to_datetime,
 Date.today.end_of_month.end_of_day.to_datetime).sum(:cost)
```

This will produce a query similar to

```
select sum(cost) from products where (date >= ... and date <= ...)
```

Comment: Oh fantastic! Can you then add this to it's own partial? Hope that's the correct terminology?

Answer (score 2):

If you already have an instantiated array (not a relation object), you can use inject:

```
@total = @products.collect(&:cost).inject {|sum, cost| sum += cost }
```

meagar's answer works better if you have the relation though.